# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi' - Gunicorn, Redhat 7, Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, redhat, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a Django Application on RHEL 7.
I have setup a virtualenv with Python 3.6 
Here is my executable gunicorn_start file.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="Garage"
DJANGODIR=/opt/garage/garage
USER=user1
GROUP=user1
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/opt/garage/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=garage.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=garage.wsgi
LOGLEVEL=error

cd $DJANGODIR
source venv/bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOGLEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

Here is my gunicorn.service file

```
    [Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user1
Group=user1
WorkingDirectory=/opt/garage
ExecStart=/opt/garage/gunicorn_start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I start gunicorn with this commands

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
```

After starting Gunicorn i check status with `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn`

I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'garage.wsgi'